# Error Open Atrium Installation

Tags: drupal, installation, open-atrium

Always i try to install OpenAtrium, i get this error (Always there)

Image Link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3MXg.jpg

I don't know why, i can install normal Drupal, but can't install OpenAtrium (I downloaded today [13 oct 14])

If i continue the installation (Refresh after this error) i can continue installing, but, after this, i get a empty/blank page

My default execution time = 90
Max allowed mysql package = 20MB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the time limit for that 90 seconds that is being exceeded? Perhaps it just needs a little more time.

max_execution_time in PHP.ini if you can do that or you could temporarily edit index.php or something with ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); (or some other figure)